# AttributeError: '_AssertRaisesContext' object has no attribute 'exception'

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am new to this and I am trying to write a unit test to catch an exception, but not sure about the logic. I tried to go on my own but ended up with an error.

I want to write the test case for handling an exception.

```
def _testcase(input,var):
        try:
            evaluate = eval(input, var)
            return float(evaluate)

        except ZeroDivisionError as error:
            print("Exception while evaluating: {}".format(error))
            return 0.0



   def test_testcase(self):
        inp = 12
        var = 0
        with self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError) as error:
            _testcase(input,var)
    
        self.assertEqual(error.exception.args[0],"Exception while evaluating: {}".format(error))
```

The error raised is the following:

```py
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abhinav/Documents/unittest/program/Abc_TESTS.py", line 85, in test_testcase
    self.assertEqual(error.exception.args[0],"Exception while evaluating: {}".format(error))
AssertionError: ZeroDivisionError not raised**
```

Comment: Did you try to de-indent the line `self.assertEqual` to be out of the context ? This is what is shown in the documentation.

Comment: okay , that was the error which i haven't gone through, I re-indented it and came up with the new error. "AssertionError: ZeroDivisionError not raised" . I have modified the code . Please check and help me out on this.

Comment: You do not raise the exception catched in `_testcase`. Add `raise error`.

Comment: how to add "raise error" , I don't know

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The `ZeroDivisionError` is caught but not raised again. If you raise it, the error message is not what you print. Thus the `assertEqual` is not very useful.

```py
def _testcase(input,var):
        try:
            evaluate = eval(input, var)
            return float(evaluate)

        except ZeroDivisionError as error:
            print("Exception while evaluating: {}".format(error))
            raise error

   def test_testcase(self):
        inp = 12
        var = 0
        with self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError) as error:
            _testcase(input,var)

        # Not very useful, or raise another Exception, but in this case
        # assertRaises should catch this exception and not ZeroDivisionError
        # self.assertEqual(error.exception.args[0],"Exception while evaluating: {}".format(error))
```

Edit: the function should return a float in any case. We can then return an additional string, empty by default.

```py
def _testcase(input,var):
        try:
            evaluate = eval(input, var)
            return (float(evaluate), "")

        except ZeroDivisionError as error:
            msg = "Exception while evaluating: {}".format(error)
            print(msg)
            return (0.0, msg)

   def test_testcase(self):
        inp = 12
        var = 0
        result, ret = _testcase(input,var)
        self.assertEqual(res, "Exception while evaluating: {}".format(error))
```

Comment: okay , but the code,  here I am returning 0.0 . I do not want to pass raise error

Comment: Then you cannot use `assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError)` since you don't want to actually raise the exception.

Comment: You can try to return a tuple `(float, bool)` where the bool is True be default, and set to False within the exception. You can then assert the value of the bool.

Comment: I edited my answer for the function to return an additional string, which is empty by default.